# How do I make a file to look like a folder?

Tags: php, file, directory

I am building something with php and I want the files to be instead of exampe shop.php to be /shop/

Ho do I do this in php? if its even possible.

Comment: Search function always comes in handy. There are hundreds of questions for this. Search for .htaccess re-writes.

Comment: taking out .php is possible.. but keeping that in folder format is not possible /shop/.. you can have like this either /shop..

Comment: i mean if for example in the shop you can go the history so its going to be " /shop/history "

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to do it.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^shop/?$ shop.php
```

Read more on URL-rewriting here :- http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php

Comment: how can i use this with other pages? theres any variable i need to use?

Comment: No, you don't. If you have to write simple rules of converting `/foo.php` to `foo`, then use the above code.

Comment: I mean i want to do this on every page, not just on one.

Comment: Make a `.htaccess` file and add all the pages and rules there. So suppose, to convert a `/test.php` to `/test`, you'd do :- `RewriteRule ^shop/?$ shop.php`

Comment: it works, but it messes my css.

Comment: fixed it, but i want to use it on a link with a get.

Comment: tried this: `RewriteRule ^/shop/history/?$ shop.php?loc=history`